# ActionBarCompat custom style

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-appcompat, android-theme

I use Android 4.2 and  minSdkVersion 17 and the application is for tablet.

i can modify the default theme (change only color for my actionbar) with my but not found.

the my manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="example.example.customtheme" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My style.xml is:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>


<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#A2a</item>
</style>
```

and MainActivity is:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

the layout is banal

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

The my problem is:
the actionbar is not color (#a2a) but is black

Comment: You don't need `android:actionBarStyle` as it's for native action bar and AppCompat doesn't use native action bar anymore. ||| Use `background` instead of `android:background` but just for the action bar style, it's a special case. ||| Maybe modify the question apart from this i didn't quite understand what doesn't work.

Comment: i have modify my post and insert the problem and delete che row usless
thanks!

Comment: **Without** `android` prefix. Read carefully what i wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this problem please update your styles.xml as following:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/ab_color</item>
        <item name="background">@color/ab_color</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

line `<item name="background">@color/ab_color</item>` was added and color was moved to colors.xml because aapt could fail to parse it otherwise.

and your colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="ab_color">#a2a</color>
</resources>
```

More details about this case: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html